# -webkit (CSS3) fade animation - jsFiddle included

Tags: html, css, webkit

So i have 3 images i want to animate using the css property, i seem to have two images working fine but cant see how to animate the third image in.

The images should animate as follows

- class="top" first for 1.5 seconds
- class="middle" second for 1.5 seconds
- class="bottom" third for 1.5 seconds

only one image should be visible at one time.

Here is the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/sEd9r/

and here is the code;

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" /> 
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1" /> 
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="cf3" class="shadow"> 
    <img class="bottom" src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21893804/s1.jpg" />
    <img class="middle" src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21893804/s2.jpg" /> 
    <img class="top" src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21893804/s3.jpg" /> 
</div>


</body>
</html>
@-webkit-keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:0;
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:0;
 }
}    

#cf3 {
    position:relative;
    height:60px;
    width:480px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#cf3 img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf3 img.top {
    -webkit-animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;

    -moz-animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -moz-animation-direction: normal;

    animation-delay:3s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:3s; /*Safari and Chrome */    
}
#cf3 img.middle {

    -webkit-animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;

    -moz-animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -moz-animation-direction: normal;
    animation-delay:1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:1.5s; /*Safari and Chrome */            
}
```

Comment: Must admit that despite writing much of the above code, I haven't tried to do this yet... I didn't know about the delay property when I wrote that, but that will be the way to go.

Comment: well most of it was lifted directly from your website ! amazing tutorials thanks Rich :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to make the animate fade from 0 to 1 so that for 1/3 of the time it's at 0. You then stagger them using delay so that only one has the 1 value at once.

I'll try and work it out at some point!

Comment: oh that seems like a more efficient method, tho due to the urgency i ended up using jQuery to animate this but it will be good to know for the future.

Thanks Rich :)